# Cannot retrieve field mongoose in client side

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My simple problem is:

I had an mongoose object at server side:

```
...
item = {
  name: "Test",
  id: 1
}
```

// item was an mongo schema

// id and name was define in model String and Number

Then I add into item new field mentions:

```
item.mention = [{ id: 1, ... }]
```

But I can't get mention at client side.

My response code:

```
res.json({ status: 1, message: 'success', data: item })
```

The response was `data: { name: "Test", id: 1 }`

I don't want to add mention into my mongo schema.

So, what's my problem?

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: `mongoose object` how did you try to modeling your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your mongoose document to an object first, then add your additional field.

Something like this:

```
let o = item.toObject();
o.mention = [{ id: 1, ... }];
res.json({ status: 1, message: 'success', data: o })
```

You could also just put this additional data in your response:

```
res.json({ status: 1, message: 'success', data: item, mention: [...] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
```

Before asign new prop for `item`.

Now you can asign value for new prop `item.mention = some_value;`

This will give you a new copy object that you can work with.

You cannot assign a new prop value to mongoose object which has not been defined before.